# Android ListView selector on hover

Tags: android, listview, selector

I'm struggling with `ListView` `selector`. I want to have gray color on list item when the user has his finger on the screen. That's all. When the user releases the finger (or move it elsewhere) the color should back to white as it should be all the time. This is my `ListView`:

```
<ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:duplicateParentState="true"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
          android:listSelector="@drawable/my_list_selector"
          android:id="@+id/list"/>
```

This is `selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
          android:state_activated="false"/>
</selector>
```

What am I doing wrong in here?

P.S. If `true` and `false` are given in the opposite way nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want to use [`android:state_pressed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#attr_android:state_pressed) instead of `android:state_activated`

code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</selector>
```

After the discussion with OP and @pskink the issue was resolved with

```
   <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: doesn't work, when I move finger somwhere else the color stays, it should dissappear

Comment: you have to remove this attribute from the default color

Comment: which attribute? from where? that comment says nothing to me

Comment: refresh the page , you will see the updates to incorporate in your code

Comment: can you explain the current behavior ?

Comment: The same as in the question. I put finger on the item it changes color but when I move finger elsewhere and release it the color stays. I want color on item only when I have my finger exactly on it and only in that case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155010/discussion-between-pavneet-singh-and-soommy12).